# U: List not lining up

Tags: html, css

I started to put together boxes and lists to see how they would all layout, and I found something I didn't expect to find. I noticed that the div that was wrapping the ul list lined up very strangely. If you publish the code below you will see the bullets of the list don't line up to the right of the black line. Instead the are sitting 20 pixels before the line. Also when I put a border around the div with the list, I thought the border would also wrap around the bullets, but the bullets are outside the border instead. Can someone explain this? So this makes it extremely hard to line lists up with other objects.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper{
        width:700px;
    }
    *{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .line {
     background: #B1B1B1;
        float: left;
        height: 340px;
        width: 1px;
    }

    #box{
        float: left;
        background:#000;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    }

    #list{
        float: left;
        border:1px #FF0000 solid;
    }


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="box"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div id="list">
         <ul>
              <li>enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum</li>
              <li>exercitation ullamco laboris</li>
              <li>eque porro quisquam est</li>
              <li>labore et dolore magnam aliquam</li>
              <li>aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur</li>
              <li>illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas</li>
              <li>modi tempora incidunt ut labore</li>
          </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah figured it out. I just changed the div to have list-style:inside; and it changes the bullets to be inside. Sorry I guess I answered my own question.

Comment: fyi, putting your code into a http://jsfiddle.net/ link makes questions like these much easier to answer

Comment: Your horrible CSS reset is confusing you. [CSS resets are bad](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20080419/reset-style-sheets-are-bad/) (the point here being that you'd better make sure you set new sensible defaults when you discard those of the browser).

Comment: you know you can self answer and accept, right?

Comment: jcolebrand what do you mean? I thought I did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bullets of a UL list are actually on the LI elemements not the UL. Beacuse the left padding and margin of the LI elements has been removed with the * rule, the bullets sit as they do. You will have to compensate, by adding a left-margin back onto your LI elements.

See here for an older but useful article: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/list-indent.html

Comment: Ah I see when I take my reset out it works. I also noticed the default browser adds padding to the ul not the li. If I set the ul padding:0 then it goes back to not working again. Thanks to all for make me understanding this.